# bash for loop, sequences and then an anomaly

Tags: bash, for-loop

Does anyone know if there is a way to specify a sequence with anomalies thrown in too in a for loop so that i can ssh to a whole heap of machines without typing in each machine number individually?

ie

```
     for i in comp{1..5,7,9}; do
         ssh root@$i" echo $i; $doOtherStuff";
     done
```

I hope this isnt too vague - im struggling to find the right words so its possible ive missed a keyword to search for in existing questions

Thanks

Comment: No, you can't mix commas and ranges. BTW, you need a space after `@$i`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't mix commas and ranges in a single brace. But you can do it with multiple levels:

```
for i in comp{{1..5},7,9}
    ...
done
```

Answer (score 2):

I hope I understand what you're trying correctly. If I do, then one way to do it is

```
 for i in {1..5} 7 9; do
     comp="comp$i"
     ssh root@$comp" echo $comp; $doOtherStuff";
 done
```

the list `i` iterates through is `1 2 3 4 5 7 9`. You can then use that to assemble the name of the machine (in the variable `comp` here) and use that the way you intended to use `i`.